# What charset and encoding does Microsoft Excel use in CHAR() function

Tags: excel, character-encoding

### Background

- I am using Microsoft Excel 2010 on Windows 7 environment. System locale is Japanese.
- I want to convert a character codepoint to a character with `CHAR()` function.

### Problem

1. `=CHAR(HEX2DEC("244E"))` returns a character `の`.

   - `244E` is the codepoint for `の` in JIS X 0208, so I had guessed that Excel uses JIS X 0208 for `CHAR()` function in Japanese environment.
2. `=CHAR(HEX2DEC("00FD"))` returns a character `ý`.

   - `00FD` is the codepoint for `ý` in ISO 8859-1 or Unicode. The character `ý` is not contained in JIS X 0208, so this result is inconsistent with the result of 1.
3. `=CHAR(HEX2DEC("00FC"))` returns a whitespace character (not `#VALUE`).

   - `00FC` is the codepoint for `ü` in ISO 8859-1 or Unicode, so this result is inconsistent with the result of 2.

I could not guess the charset and encoding that Microsoft Excel uses in `CHAR()` function.

### Question

What charset and encoding does Microsoft Excel use in `CHAR()` function?

Comment: `=ChrW()` results `#NAME?` in Excel 2010.

Comment: Excel 2013 or later has `UNICHAR()` function, but it doesn't help. It is completely Unicode-based function, and it seems independent of the system locale.